# Android tint image with 2 different color

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, tint

I am trying to tint the image left half with orange, right with maroon color. I wrote my code, but whenever I tried, it returned just solid orange and maroon color. So this is what I am trying to do.

I want to tint the left and right with orange and maroon with good amount so it will be like

[image: Success]

[image: This is my image that is failed]

Like this, mine is not working like the example. Here is my code.

```
public Bitmap toHokie(Bitmap bmpOriginal) {
    int width, height;

    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(),
            bmpOriginal.getHeight(), bmpOriginal.getConfig());
    height = bmOut.getHeight();
    width = bmOut.getWidth();
    int orangeFilter = new Color().rgb(255, 165, 0);
    int maroonFilter = new Color().rgb(139, 0, 0);
    for (int j = 0; j < height - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - 1; i++) {
            int newColor = (int) ((double) (bmOut.getPixel(i, j) * 0.3) + ((double) (orangeFilter * 0.7)));

            bmOut.setPixel(i, j, newColor);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < height - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = width / 2; i < width - 1; i++) {
            double newColor = (bmOut.getPixel(i, j) * 0.3 + maroonFilter * 0.7);
            bmOut.setPixel(i, j, (int) newColor);
        }
    }
    return bmOut;
}
```

Actually, for my second try, it is now better than the before, but still it is wired... like this

[image: I guess something is working....]

I fixed like this.

```
    public Bitmap toHokie(Bitmap bmpOriginal) {
    int width, height;

    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(),
            bmpOriginal.getHeight(), bmpOriginal.getConfig());
    height = bmOut.getHeight();
    width = bmOut.getWidth();
    int orangeFilter = new Color().rgb(255, 165, 0);
    int maroonFilter = new Color().rgb(139, 0, 0);
    for (int j = 0; j < height - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - 1; i++) {
            int newColor = (int) ((bmpOriginal.getPixel(i, j) * 0.7) + ((orangeFilter * 0.3)));

            bmOut.setPixel(i, j, newColor);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < height - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = width / 2; i < width - 1; i++) {
            double newColor = (bmpOriginal.getPixel(i, j) * 0.3 + maroonFilter * 0.7);
            bmOut.setPixel(i, j, (int) newColor);
        }
    }
    return bmOut;
}
```

Comment: Add colors and then add alpha property to them, that should do it, I reckon.

Comment: looking for same, did you get the solution? if yes, can you please post it as answer, you will get chance to grab some points, because lot of people looking for this(see viewed 100+ times)

Answer (score 1):

this is xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/sachin_bg1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#4a8cd5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#f21616"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

use this code in onCreate method

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    Drawable background1 = layout1.getBackground();
    background1.setAlpha(100);

    LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    Drawable background2 = layout2.getBackground();
    background2.setAlpha(100);
```